# Как нарисовать повёрнутый квадрат с помощью обычных линий?

Tags: javascript, canvas, геометрия

Вот как на изображении квадрат построенный на гипотенузе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
xxx(); onresize = xxx

function xxx() {
  const w = canvas.width  = innerWidth
  const h = canvas.height = innerHeight
  const cw = w/2, ch = h/2, s = (w+h) / 2 

  const p1 = { x: cw - s * 0.09,  y: ch + s * 0.09 }
  const p2 = { x: cw + s * 0.09,  y: ch - s * 0.09 }
  const a = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x)
  const b = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y)

  context.lineCap = 'round'

  // Нижний квадрат
  context.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x, p1.y + a) // левая линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y + a) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y + a, p1.x + a, p1.y + a) // нижняя линия

  // Правый квадрат
  context.strokeStyle = 'lightblue'
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a + b, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y - b, p1.x + a + b, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия
  line(p1.x + a + b, p1.y - b, p1.x + a + b, p1.y) // правая линия

  // Треугольник
  context.strokeStyle = 'tomato'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия

  function line(x1,y1, x2,y2) {
    context.lineWidth = 4
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(x1, y1)
    context.lineTo(x2, y2)
    context.stroke()
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Я так понимаю нужно как-то хитро перемножить стороны на косинусы и синусы, но я не настолько хитёр (

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как-то так:

```
let dist = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)
let alpha = Math.atan2(b,a) + Math.PI/2
let dx = Math.cos(alpha)*dist;
let dy = -Math.sin(alpha)*dist;
line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + dx, p1.y + dy);
line(p2.x, p2.y, p2.x + dx, p2.y + dy);
line(p1.x + dx, p1.y + dy, p2.x + dx, p2.y + dy);
```

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')

requestAnimationFrame(xxx)

function xxx(t) {
  const w = canvas.width  = innerWidth
  const h = canvas.height = innerHeight
  const cw = w/2, ch = h/2, s = (w+h) / 2 
  let s1 = 0.03 + Math.sin(t/1000)*0.02
  let s2 = 0.07 + Math.cos(t/2000)*0.02
  const p1 = { x: cw - s * s1,  y: ch + s * s2 }
  const p2 = { x: cw + s * s1,  y: ch - s * s2 }
  const a = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x)
  const b = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y)

  context.lineCap = 'round'
  context.strokeStyle = 'orange'
  
  let dist = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)
  let alpha = Math.atan2(b,a) + Math.PI/2
  let dx = Math.cos(alpha)*dist;
  let dy = -Math.sin(alpha)*dist;
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + dx, p1.y + dy);
  line(p2.x, p2.y, p2.x + dx, p2.y + dy);
  line(p1.x + dx, p1.y + dy, p2.x + dx, p2.y + dy);
  
  // Нижний квадрат
  context.strokeStyle = 'lightgreen'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x, p1.y + a) // левая линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y + a) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y + a, p1.x + a, p1.y + a) // нижняя линия

  // Правый квадрат
  context.strokeStyle = 'lightblue'
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a + b, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y - b, p1.x + a + b, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия
  line(p1.x + a + b, p1.y - b, p1.x + a + b, p1.y) // правая линия

  // Треугольник
  context.strokeStyle = 'tomato'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия
  
  requestAnimationFrame(xxx)

}


function line(x1,y1, x2,y2) {
  context.lineWidth = 4
  context.beginPath()
  context.moveTo(x1, y1)
  context.lineTo(x2, y2)
  context.stroke()
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Квадрат становится кривой если изменить длину одной из сторон треугольника `const p2 = { x: cw + s * 0.07,  y: ch - s * 0.3 }`. Я так полагаю нужно `Math.PI/2` вот здесь `let alpha = b/dist + Math.PI/2` как-то динамически менять ?

Comment: но нужно менять в 2х строчках, я вроде это проверил

Comment: если в 2х меняю, то тоже кривой

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ да, увидел.. сейчас верну арктангенс)

Comment: Можно и `acos` использовать  вроде. Спасибо, как всегда выручаешь )

Answer (score 4):

Чтобы не рассчитывать координаты точек самому, можно перепоручить это элементу `canvas`, просто повернув его как нужно, перед началом рисования.

Для поворота можно воспользоваться методом [`.rotate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate), аргументом является угол в радинах.

При этом подходе достаточно рисовать обычные прямоугольники и просто поворачивать их на нужный угол.

Для того, чтобы настройки поворотов не затрагивали весь canvas можно сохранять настройки перед рисованием и сбрасывать их после. Для этого можно воспользоваться методами [`.save`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/save) и [`.restore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/restore).

Также нужно задать точку, вокруг которой будет производиться поворот. Сделать это можно с помощью метода [`.translate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

Чтобы облегчить работу с углами можно отразить холст относительно оси `x` с помощью метода [`.scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), после этого оси будут привычно направлены: x - влево, y - вверх.

Пример:

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
xxx();
onresize = xxx

function xxx() {
  const w = canvas.width = innerWidth
  const h = canvas.height = innerHeight
  const cw = w / 2,
    ch = h / 2,
    s = (w + h) / 2

  const p1 = {
    x: cw - s * 0.09,
    y: ch + s * 0.09
  }
  const p2 = {
    x: cw + s * 0.09,
    y: ch - s * 0.09
  }
  const a = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x)
  const b = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y)

  context.lineCap = 'round'

  // Нижний квадрат
  rect('lightgreen', {
    x: p2.x,
    y: p1.y
  }, b, b, Math.PI);

  // Правый квадрат
  rect('lightblue', p2, a, a, -Math.PI / 2);

  rect('gray', p1, Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), Math.PI / 4);

  // Треугольник
  context.strokeStyle = 'tomato'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия

  function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(x1, y1)
    context.lineTo(x2, y2)
    context.stroke()
  }

  function rect(color, point, width, height, angle = 0) {
    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.translate(point.x, point.y);
    context.scale(1, -1)
    context.rotate(angle);
    line(0, 0, 0, height);
    line(0, height, width, height);
    line(width, height, width, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Для произвольного прямоугольного треугольника, можно воспользоваться тем, что отношение катетов дает тангенс угла, на который нужно повернуть, следовательно нужный угол можно узнать с помощью метода [`Math.atan`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/atan)

```js
const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
xxx();
onresize = xxx

function xxx() {
  const w = canvas.width = innerWidth
  const h = canvas.height = innerHeight
  const cw = w / 2,
    ch = h / 2,
    s = (w + h) / 2

  const p1 = {
    x: cw - s * 0.09,
    y: ch + s * 0.09
  }
  const p2 = {
    x: cw + s * 0.09,
    y: ch
  }
  const a = Math.abs(p2.x - p1.x)
  const b = Math.abs(p2.y - p1.y)

  context.lineCap = 'round'

  // Нижний квадрат
  rect('lightgreen', {
    x: p2.x,
    y: p1.y
  }, a, a, Math.PI);

  // Правый квадрат
  rect('lightblue', p2, b, b, -Math.PI / 2);

  rect('gray', p1, Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b), Math.atan(b / a));

  // Треугольник
  context.strokeStyle = 'tomato'
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y) // нижняя линия
  line(p1.x + a, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // правая линия
  line(p1.x, p1.y, p1.x + a, p1.y - b) // верхняя линия

  function line(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    context.lineWidth = 4;
    context.beginPath()
    context.moveTo(x1, y1)
    context.lineTo(x2, y2)
    context.stroke()
  }

  function rect(color, point, width, height, angle = 0) {
    context.save();
    context.strokeStyle = color;
    context.translate(point.x, point.y);
    context.scale(1, -1)
    context.rotate(angle);
    line(0, 0, 0, height);
    line(0, height, width, height);
    line(width, height, width, 0);
    context.restore();
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @ᅠhᅠ, точно, а мне почему-то так понравился прямоугольник получившийся, что забыл что он квадратом должен быть :) тогда можно упростить метод rect, и только одно значение передавать

Answer (score 3):

Формула вращения на угол a относительно x_0, y_0:

```
X = x_0 + (x − x_0) * cos⁡(a) − (y − y_0 ) * sin⁡(a)
Y = y_0 + (y − y_0) * cos⁡(a) + (x − x_0 ) * sin⁡(a)
```

x, y - исходные координаты

Comment: Я не могу это разобрать без живого примера